# Slider_ValueChanged Does not work properly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, slider

I'm Trying to bind a `TextBlock` to a `Slider` Value.

So what I did is to set the text value of the `TextBlock` to the value of the slider with the `ValueChanged` event. Here is my `XAML`:

```
<TextBlock Name="PartyNumber" Text="1"  
           FontSize="40" FontFamily="Calibri" 
           Width="100" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green"/>
<Slider Name="PartyNumberSlider" Grid.Row="5" 
        Width="340" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}" 
        Height="100" Maximum="12" 
        Minimum="1" Value="1" 
        ValueChanged="PartyNumberSlider_ValueChanged" />
```

My code behind is like this:

```
private void PartyNumberSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    PartyNumber.Text = PartyNumberSlider.Value.ToString();
}
```

When I launch the app, the `ValueChanged` event fires upon initialisation, and it handles and `NullReferenceExeption`.

I do not even get to change the slider's value.

So any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dropped what you have written into a WPF application and it works as expected.  I might suggest doing this with an actual data binding:

```
<TextBlock Name="PartyNumber" Text="{Binding ElementName=PartyNumberSlider, Path=Value}" 
    FontSize="40" FontFamily="Calibri" Width="100" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Green"/>
<Slider Name="PartyNumberSlider" Grid.Row="5" Width="340" Height="100" Maximum="12" Minimum="1" Value="1" />
```

So you do not need the event or code behind. If you need to handle or process this value you can also bind both values to the same property in your code behind or viewmodel.

Anyway, where exactly is the NullReferenceExeption being thrown? If you aren't sure, go to Debug -> Exceptions and try ticking "Thrown" next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and try to run again.

Comment: Thank. I find thz binding way is better the what I've done, only if it shows only integer.

Comment: No problem. Setting "IsSnapToTickEnabled=True" on the slider will limit the slider to the "TickFrequency" interval, which, when set to 1, will show integers.

Comment: Well I know that, but this property is not supported by windows phone.